# Purpose of perfect forwarding for Callable argument in invocation expression?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, auto, perfect-forwarding

In Scott Meyer's book [Effective Modern C++ on page 167](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZDhIBQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=effective%20modern%20c%2B%2B&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjk6LrJ3rHMAhXBCsAKHdcFDtIQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=timeFuncInvocation&f=false) (of the print version), he gives the following example:

```
auto timeFuncInvocation = [](auto&& func, auto&&... params) {
  // start timer;
  std::forward<decltype(func)>(func)(
    std::forward<decltype(params)>(params)...
  );
  // stop timer and record elapsed time;
};
```

I completely understand the perfect forwarding of `params`, but it is unclear to me when perfect forwarding of `func` would ever be relevant.  In other words, what are the advantages of the above over the following:

```
auto timeFuncInvocation = [](auto&& func, auto&&... params) {
  // start timer;
  func(
    std::forward<decltype(params)>(params)...
  );
  // stop timer and record elapsed time;
};
```

Comment: When `func` has a ref-qualified function call operator.

Comment: Ohhhhhh.... makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the same purpose as for arguments: so when `Func::operator()` is a ref-qualified:

```
struct Functor
{
    void operator ()() const &  { std::cout << "lvalue functor\n"; }
    void operator ()() const && { std::cout << "rvalue functor\n"; }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/51adc1b1a2444f51)

Comment: Remove the `const` part, then it makes *better* sense.

Comment: no, as `const` rvalue reference will prefer `const &` overload to `&&` overload: `const Functor f() { return Functor{}; }; f()();` [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e1b8f476f9e3f05)