# How do correctly use a callable passed through forwarding reference?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, decltype, perfect-forwarding

I'm used to pass lambda functions (and other callables) to template functions -- and use them -- as follows

```
template <typename F>
auto foo (F && f)
 {
   // ...

   auto x = std::forward<F>(f)(/* some arguments */);

   // ... 
 }
```

I mean: I'm used to pass them through a forwarding reference and call them passing through `std::forward`.

Another Stack Overflow user argue (see comments to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55784315/6022656)) that this, calling the functional two or more time, it's dangerous because it's semantically invalid and potentially dangerous (and maybe also Undefined Behavior) when the function is called with a r-value reference.

I've partially misunderstand what he means (my fault) but the remaining doubt is if the following `bar()` function (with an indubitable multiple `std::forward` over the same object) it's correct code or it's (maybe only potentially) dangerous.

```
template <typename F>
auto bar (F && f)
 {
   using A = typename decltype(std::function{std::forward<F>(f)})::result_type;

   std::vector<A>  vect;

   for ( auto i { 0u }; i < 10u ; ++i )
      vect.push_back(std::forward<F>(f)());

   return vect;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say the general rule applies in this case. You're not supposed to do anything with a variable after it was moved/forwarded from, except maybe assigning to it.

Thus...

> How do correctly use a callable passed through forwarding reference?

Only forward if you're sure it won't be called again (i.e. on last call, if at all).

If it's never called more than once, there is no reason to not forward.

---

As for why your snippet could be dangerous, consider following functor:

```
template <typename T>
struct foo
{
    T value;
    const T &operator()() const & {return value;}
    T &&operator()() && {return std::move(value);}
};
```

As an optimization, `operator()` when called on an rvalue allows caller to move from `value`.

Now, your template wouldn't compile if given this functor (because, as T.C. said, `std::function` wouldn't be able to determine return type in this case).

But if we changed it a bit:

```
template <typename A, typename F>
auto bar (F && f)
 {    
   std::vector<A>  vect;

   for ( auto i { 0u }; i < 10u ; ++i )
      vect.push_back(std::forward<F>(f)());

   return vect;
 }
```

then it would [break spectacularly](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8d309f89ebdfa58) when given this functor.

Comment: Very nice and instructive example.

Answer (score 4):

Forward is just a conditional move.

Therefore, to forward the same thing multiple times is, generally speaking, as dangerous as moving from it multiple times.

Unevaluated forwards don't move anything, so those don't count.

Routing through `std::function` adds a wrinkle: that deduction only works on function pointers and on function objects with a single function call operator that is not `&&` qualified. For these, rvalue and lvalue invocation are always equivalent if both compiles.

Answer (score 1):

If you're either going to just forward the callable to another place or simply call the callable exactly once, I would argue that using `std::forward` is the correct thing to do in general. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36920485/purpose-of-perfect-forwarding-for-callable-argument-in-invocation-expression/36920686#36920686), this will sort of preserve the value category of the callable and allow the "correct" version of a potentially overloaded function call operator to be called.

The problem in the original thread was that the callable was being called in a loop, thus potentially invoked more than once. The concrete example from the other thread was

```
template <typename F>
auto map(F&& f) const
{
    using output_element_type = decltype(f(std::declval<T>()));

    auto sequence = std::make_unique<Sequence<output_element_type>>();

    for (const T& element : *this)
        sequence->push(f(element));

    return sequence;
}
```

Here, I believe that calling `std::forward<F>(f)(element)` instead of `f(element)`, i.e.,

```
template <typename F>
auto map(F&& f) const
{
    using output_element_type = decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(std::declval<T>()));

    auto sequence = std::make_unique<Sequence<output_element_type>>();

    for (const T& element : *this)
        sequence->push(std::forward<F>(f)(element));

    return sequence;
}
```

would be potentially problematic. As far as my understanding goes, the defining characteristic of an rvalue is that it cannot explicitly be referred to. In particular, there is naturally no way for the same prvalue to be used in an expression more than once (at least I can't think of one). Furthermore, as far as my understanding goes, if you're using `std::move` or `std::forward` or whatever other way to obtain an xvalue, even on the same original object, the result will be a new xvalue every time. Thus, there also cannot possibly be a way to refer to the same xvalue more than once. Since the same rvalue cannot be used more than once, I would argue  (see also comments underneath [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55784315/2064761)) that it would generally be a valid thing for an overloaded function call operator to do something that can only be done once in case the call happens on an rvalue, for example:

```
class MyFancyCallable
{
public:
    void operator () & { /* do some stuff */ }
    void operator () && { /* do some stuff in a special way that can only be done once */ }
};
```

The implementation of `MyFancyCallable` may assume that a call that would pick the `&&`-qualified version cannot possibly happen more than once (on the given object). Thus, I would consider forwarding the same callable into more than one call to be semantically broken.

Of course, technically, there is no universal definition of what it actually means to forward or move an object. In the end, it's really up to the implementation of the particular types involved to assign meaning there. Thus, you may simply specify as part of your interface that potential callables passed to your algorithm must be able to deal with being called multiple times on an rvalue that refers to the same object. However, doing so pretty much goes against all the conventions for how the rvalue reference mechanism is generally used in C++, and I don't really see what there possibly would be to be gained from doing this…

Comment: One of this centuries I'll understand perfect forwarding. Nice answer but the HolyBlackCat's one give us a simple but clear example of the practical problem. Anyway, you're right: thanks for your patience.

Comment: @max66 you may wanna check out [this site](http://www.thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html) if you haven't already. It gives a quite nice explanation of it all.