# Should std::forward be used when the forwarding reference is not passed to another function but a member function is called on it?

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding, forwarding-reference

Examples of `std::forward` I've seen use it when passing the argument to another function, such as this common one from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward):

```
template<class T>
void wrapper(T&& arg) 
{
    // arg is always lvalue
    foo(std::forward<T>(arg)); // Forward as lvalue or as rvalue, depending on T
}
```

It also has a more complicated case:

> if a wrapper does not just forward its argument, but calls a member function on the argument, and forwards its result

```
// transforming wrapper 
template<class T>
void wrapper(T&& arg)
{
    foo(forward<decltype(forward<T>(arg).get())>(forward<T>(arg).get()));
}
```

But what happens when I *only* call the member function without passing the result to another function?

```
template<class T>
auto wrapper(T&& arg)
{
    return std::forward<T>(arg).get();
}
```

In this case, is it useful to call `std::forward` or is `arg.get()` equivalent? Or does it depend on `T`?

EDIT: I've found a case where they are not equivalent;

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    int get() & {
        return 0;
    }

    int get() && {
        return 1;
    }
};

template<class T>
auto wrapper_fwd(T&& arg)
{
    return std::forward<T>(arg).get();
}

template<class T>
auto wrapper_no(T&& arg)
{
    return arg.get();
}
```

[`wrapper_fwd(A{})` returns `1` and `wrapper_no(A{})` returns `0`](https://godbolt.org/z/abMqfj9EE).

But in my actual use-case `arg` is a lambda and `operator()` isn't overloaded like this. Is there still a possible difference?

Comment: Try `std::cout << wrapper_fwd(A{}) << wrapper_no(A{}) << "\n";`

Comment: Thanks! I did, I guess you saw while I was editing the second time. So I have a follow-up question at the end.

Comment: Probably no difference if your only use case is lambdas as there is no way to specify the ref qualification. Other similar questions seem to imply that ref qualification is the only difference here [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36920485/purpose-of-perfect-forwarding-for-callable-argument-in-invocation-expression/36920686#36920686)